# Assigning one UNITID to multiple areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, fields-attributes, update

I have a city wide water distribution network that will undergo a flushing process over the next couple of years. I need to keep track of what segments of pipe have been flushed. The work is divided into zones, and I know what pipe unique ID is in each zone.

Say that I have one segment of pipe that belongs to multiple flushing zones. How could I design a field that allows one attribute to belong to multiple zones, so that when I indicate if a zone is complete it gets updated with the most recent completion date?

Are there any ways to make a field like this? Then I am thinking I could write  a query that says IF: (unitID) belongs to zone (1,2,3, etc.) THEN update new field with the given date.

Any thoughts on this?